# How does the second line of code able to close fd 3 for grep and not ls?

Tags: bash, io

```
# Redirecting only stderr to a pipe.
exec 3>&1                              # Save current "value" of stdout.
ls -l 2>&1 >&3 3>&- | grep bad 3>&-    # Close fd 3 for 'grep' (but not 'ls').
#              ^^^^   ^^^^
exec 3>&-                              # Now close it for the remainder of the script.
```

I was looking through https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html trying to understand how input and output are redirected in bash. I don't understand how the second line of code closes fd 3 for 'grep' but not for ls. What I understand is stderr of ls is directed to stdout and then stdout is redirected to fd 3 and then fd 3 is closed before the pipe command. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please don't use the ABS as a reference -- it's full of bad-practice examples and outdated information. Consider the bash-hackers' wiki: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial, http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection; or the Wooledge BashGuide: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Redirection

Answer (score 0):

Your example *does* close FD 3 for `ls` (contrary to the misleading comment text), but after making FD 1 a copy of it.

```
exec 3>&1  # creates a backup of FD 1 on FD 3

# for ls:
# - stderr points to the pipe (which was stdout for the left-hand side before any
#   redirections).
# - stdout points to backup of prior stdout (copied from fd 3);
# - fd 3 is closed
ls -l 2>&1 >&3 3>&- \
 | grep bad 3>&-  # for grep:
                  # - stdin is the output from `ls -l` due to the pipeline
                  # - stderr is regular TTY stderr
                  # - fd 3 is closed
```

Note that closing FD 3 isn't actually important here -- the code would work just as well if it didn't do so, as neither `ls` nor `grep` does anything with this file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

> Close fd 3 for 'grep' (but not 'ls').

This comment is wrong. fd 3 is closed for both commands seeing as both have their own `3>&-`.

Why are there three `3>&-`'s in the script? It's because ls and grep inherit copies of all of the parent script's file descriptors. Each of the three processes has its own fd 3 that the script carefully closes. It's not really necessary to close any of these. It's really just the script author being extra careful--always a good thing.

---

For illustrative purposes, let's say the script is executed with `>stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt`, so stdout goes to one file and stderr to another.

```
# 1: stdout.txt
# 2: stderr.txt
```

Now let's see what happens with each command.

#### exec

```
exec 3>&1
```

This duplicates stdout to fd 3.

```
# 1: stdout.txt
# 2: stderr.txt
# 3: stdout.txt
```

#### ls

When ls forks it inherits the parent fds, except stdout is first redirected to the pipe to grep.

```
# Before
# 1: [pipe]
# 2: stderr.txt
# 3: stdout.txt

ls -l 2>&1 >&3 3>&-
```

`2>&1` redirects stderr to the pipe stdout is connected to, so `2: [pipe]`. Then `>&3` redirects stdout to fd 3, so `1: stdout.txt`. Then `3>&-` closes fd 3.

```
# After
# 1: stdout.txt
# 2: [pipe]
# 3: [closed]
```

#### grep

Now what about grep? It also inherits the parent's file descriptors.

```
# Before
# 1: stdout.txt
# 2: stderr.txt
# 3: stdout.txt

grep bad 3>&-
```

fd 3 is useless, so it's closed.

```
# After
# 1: stdout.txt
# 2: stderr.txt
# 3: [closed]
```

#### exec

Finally, the parent script closes the now unneeded fd 3.

```
# Before
# 1: stdout.txt
# 2: stderr.txt
# 3: stdout.txt

exec 3>&-

# After
# 1: stdout.txt
# 2: stderr.txt
# 3: [closed]
```